# How to add JS Confirmation popup when clicking an #AJAX button in custom module?

Tags: ajax, javascript

```
$form['button4'] = array(
'#value' => 'RESET',
'#type' => 'submit',
'#submit' => array('form_test_form_button4'),
'#ajax' => array(
  'callback' => 'ajax_example_submit_driven_callback1',
    'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),
    'wrapper' => 'deletevalue',
    'event' => 'click',
),

);
```

This is the RESET button I want to ask Are you sure?.

AJAX submit also working fine. But POPUP Confirmation not working properly.Please anyone guide to me?

If user click the OK button the data will be reset.

JS

`$('#edit-button7').on('click', function(){
var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to reset?");
});`

If user click the CANCEL button also data was reset.

Comment: Hint: you need to do it from JS side

Comment: @Mołot From JS Side also i did it. but the form was submitted. Please refer my question

Comment: You can actually do this through the form api. I know it is on here somewhere. I will post when I find it.

Comment: You need to add "if(!r) return false;" to prevent the submission on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could have sworn it was on so somewhere. But I could not find it quickly. You can try this using the form API in your button. Found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1182224#comment-4573996)

```
 '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'if(!confirm("Really Delete?")){return false;}')
```

You can of course use JS as you were. I think you were missing the `return false;`